# SPRING MVC : How to pass the radio button value which is clicked to controller?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jsp, java-ee-8

I am using Spring MVC controller.

Is it possible to set an object in the path value in a radio button ?

below my form inside my jsp

```
<spring:url value="/update" var="update" htmlEscape="false"/>
<form:form action="${update}" method="post" modelAttribute="addressForm">
     <c:forEach items="${addresses}" var="address">
     <form:radiobutton path="address" value="${address}" label="${address.city}"/>
     </c:forEach>
         <input type="submit" value="Confirm"/>
</form:form>
```

And my controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/update", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String chooseAddress(@Valid final AddressForm form, final BindingResult bindingResult,
                                         final RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes){
    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()){
        System.out.println("Erros");
    }else{
        System.out.println("NO Erros");
    }

    return REDIRECT_URL;
}
```

Here is my AddressForm

```
public class AddressForm implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 3734278553292263688L;

@NotNull
AddressDTO address;

public AddressDTO getAddress() {
    return address;
}

public void setAddress(AddressDTO address) {
    this.address = address;
}
}
```

I want to retrieve the selected object address from my controller but I have an Error `bindingResult.hasErrors()` return true with the following error and form with address null

```
   org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult: 1 errors
   Field error in object 'addressForm' on field 'address': rejected 
   value []; codes 
[typeMismatch.AddressForm.address,typeMismatch.address,typeMismatch.com.data.AddressDTO,typeMismatch]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [AddressForm.address,address]; arguments []; default message [address]]; default message [Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'com.data.AddressDTO' for property 'address'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'com.data.AddressDTO' for property 'address': no matching editors or conversion strategy found]
```

Comment: did you try to https://stackoverflow.com/a/59749768/175554

Comment: @özkanpakdil I have a list which already contains the addresses
I need to choose between these addresses

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to pass in the path the address id like that :

```
<spring:url value="/update" var="update" htmlEscape="false"/>
<form:form action="${update}" method="post" modelAttribute="addressForm">
 <c:forEach items="${addresses}" var="address">
 <form:radiobutton path="id"label="${address.city}"/>
 </c:forEach>
     <input type="submit" value="Confirm"/>
</form:form>

public class AddressForm implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 3734278553292263688L;

@NotNull
String id;

public String getId() {
  return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
   this.id = id;
}
}
```

And you recover in your action the address by id or code since you already have list.